# How to fix "Missing classes" error in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml

When I am trying to make new activity in Android Studio 
these errors happen, before this error I created few activities normally (without any errors):

```
The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout (    Add constraint-layout library dependency to the project, Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

Dependency library:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:29.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:11.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Post your code of dependency library here.

Comment: edited first post

Comment: You have project of AndroidX,and you said you created activities without any error,So check in those activity about this :android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout, android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout, android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar ...And convert it into androidx depenedency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use AndroidX libraries and Support libraries in same project. Migrate to AndroidX from menu, it will replace package names and dependencies.

Your project is adding widgets from Support libraries instead of AndroidX which is causing this issue.

[image]

If you still get errors, replace old package names from the ones in the list:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: @Niklaus go to your laylut files and replace package name for constraint layout to `androidx.widget.constraintLayout`

Answer (score 3):

You've mixed up `AndroidX` dependency with `AppCompat`. Either migrate it to AndroidX from Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX or use AppCompat.

As in your code, you have used both dependencies for `Constraint Layout`. The simplest solution for your problem is to remove the line

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```